How to properly align text in radial plot in R
I have this data below:
data_melted <- structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("SJLIFE", "CCSS"), class = "factor"), 
    SN_types = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), levels = c("Any SN", "SMN", "NMSC", 
    "Breast cancer", "Thyroid cancer", "Meningioma", "Sarcoma"
    ), class = "factor"), AF_by = c("Combined", "Combined", "Combined", 
    "Combined", "Combined", "Combined", "Combined", "Combined", 
    "Combined", "Combined", "Combined", "Combined", "Combined", 
    "Combined"), value = c(0.536, 0.467, 0.688, 0.704, 0.866, 
    0.423, 0.316, 0.435, 0.323, 0.577, 0.743, 0.664, 0.444, 0.362
    ), new_value = c(54, 47, 69, 70, 87, 42, 32, 44, 32, 58, 
    74, 66, 44, 36)), row.names = c(6L, 12L, 18L, 24L, 30L, 36L, 
42L, 48L, 54L, 60L, 66L, 72L, 78L, 84L), class = "data.frame")

I am using this code which makes the plot. However, I am having difficulty aligning the text properly around the bars. I want the text right on top of each bar 90 degree to each bar maintaining the angular position of the radial plot. How do I do it?
angle_increment.AF <- 360 / 14
angle_increment.SN_type <- 360 / 7    
ggplot(data_melted, aes(x = SN_types, y = new_value, fill = variable, label = new_value)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = seq(1.5, 19.5, by = 3), color = "black", linetype = "dashed") + # If you want to include a vertical line
      geom_hline(yintercept = 100) +
      geom_text(aes(angle = 0 + (angle_increment.AF * (as.numeric(as.factor(SN_types)) - 1))),  # Adjust angle of text labels
                position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = 0.9, size = 5, color = "black") +  # Adjust label position and size
      scale_fill_manual(values = c(darker_sjlife, darker_ccss), labels = c("SJLIFE", "CCSS")) +  # Specify colors for SJLIFE and CCSS bars
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) +  # Custom grid lines from 0 to 1 by 0.25
      coord_polar() +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray", linetype = "dotted"),  # Adjust major grid lines
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),  # Remove minor grid lines
            axis.line = element_blank(),   # Remove axis lines
            axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5, angle = angle_increment, color = "black"),  # Center SN type labels within grid
            axis.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"),  # Adjust axis text size
            axis.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),  # Adjust axis title size
            legend.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),  # Adjust legend title size
            legend.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black")) +  # Adjust legend text size
      labs(title = "",
           x = NULL, y = "(%)",
           fill = "Cohort")


You are making this far harder than you need to. Using coord_curvedpolar from the geomtextpath package will nicely arrange the radial labels. You can also use geom_textpath in place of geom_text so that you don't need to calculate the angles of the labels.
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(data_melted, aes(x = SN_types, y = new_value, 
                        fill = variable, label = new_value)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(1.5, 19.5, by = 3), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_textpath(position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = 1, size = 5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('deepskyblue4', 'orangered'), 
                    labels = c("SJLIFE", "CCSS")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) + 
  coord_curvedpolar() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray", linetype = "dotted"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),  
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black")) + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = "(%)", fill = "Cohort")


Note that you didn't include the definition of the colors darker_sjlife or darker_ccss so I have just chosen a couple of random colors to replace them.

Why do some numbers look inverted? How do I fix that?

@MAPK some of the numbers have to be upside down in a radial plot. The numbers on the bottom half of the plot are flipped to make them readable. If you want them all to be in the same orientation as the bars you can add upright = FALSE inside geom_textpath

Not as nice as the geomtextpath approach by Allan when it comes to the axis text but another option would be to switch to coord_radial and guide_axis_theta introduced in ggplot2 3.5.0:
library(ggplot2)

packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.5.0'

ggplot(data_melted, aes(x = SN_types, y = new_value, fill = variable, label = new_value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(1.5, 19.5, by = 3), color = "black", linetype = "dashed") + # If you want to include a vertical line
  geom_hline(yintercept = 100) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      # angle = 0 + (angle_increment.AF * (as.numeric(as.factor(SN_types)) - 1))
    ), # Adjust angle of text labels
    position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = 0, size = 5, color = "black"
  ) + # Adjust label position and size
  # scale_fill_manual(values = c(darker_sjlife, darker_ccss), labels = c("SJLIFE", "CCSS")) + # Specify colors for SJLIFE and CCSS bars
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) + # Custom grid lines from 0 to 1 by 0.25
  # coord_polar() +
  coord_radial(rotate_angle = TRUE, expand = FALSE) +
  guides(
    theta = guide_axis_theta(angle = 0)
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray", linetype = "dotted"), # Adjust major grid lines
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # Remove minor grid lines
    axis.line = element_blank(), # Remove axis lines
    # axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5, angle = angle_increment, color = "black"), # Center SN type labels within grid
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"), # Adjust axis text size
    axis.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"), # Adjust axis title size
    legend.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"), # Adjust legend title size
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black")
  ) + # Adjust legend text size
  labs(
    title = "",
    x = NULL, y = "(%)",
    fill = "Cohort"
  )


